# No resource found error

Tags: android, eclipse

I imported project cloned from git and get this error, while in other computer not:

[image]

[image]

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

However, I can find the `Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Large.Inverse` inside `styles.xml` inside my Android SDK folder.

I have tried to clean, reimport project and restart Eclipse, but nothing works.

My Eclipse is different with other computer though. Mine uses `Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)`, while other computer uses `Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)`

Anyone can advise what could be wrong?

Comment: is everything in Android SDK manger the same as your other computers?

Comment: For sure both of us have downloaded all necessary SDK Platform and Google APIs, but working computer does not update the Android SDK Tools . And we cannot do copy and paste the Android SDK folder..

Comment: Remove this line and re-write this(style) line again. I had this problem when imported cloned github project in android-studio. Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it by this step:

- Create **NEW** workspace for that project **ONLY**
- Re-clone the project
- Import the project (if needed)

Don't understand why create new workspace removes the error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suggest to use Android Studio for Android development.